# Incluir un archivo en Codeingniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, php7

me gustaria saber si esta es la forma correcta de incluir un archivo en en home o página de inicio en Codeingniter 4.
La situación es la siguiente, tengo mi home o pagina de inicio normal con su modelo y su controlador.
Ahora bien he colocado en la carpeta Layouts un archivo llamado hello.php el cual dentro tiene html
mi idea es incluir este archivo en algunas páginas, una de ellas es el home, lo he hecho usando $this->include y me funciona bien, lo que me gustaría saber es si lo estoy haciendo correctamente.
Adjunto la estructura del código para una mejor compresión.

````
<?= $this->section('content')?>

<h2>Hello Word</h2>
<p>Nonecesito incluir el archivo hello.php aqui y no n el main</p>

<?= $this->include('Front/layout/hello')?>

<?= $this->endSection()?> ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes un Layout master por ejemplo `default.php`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Layout</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?= $this->renderSection('content') ?>
</body>
</html>
```

y ese lo quieres utilizar en una vista `hello.php` lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
<?= $this->extend('default') ?>

<?= $this->section('content') ?>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
<?= $this->endSection() ?>
```

El extend lo que hace es tomar el layout master e incluirle los section correspondientes.

Para más información puedes visualizarlo directamente en la página de [View Layouts de Codeigniter](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/outgoing/view_layouts.html).